# Discrete math question using PigeonHole

Tags: discrete-mathematics

QUE:
There are 30 students in the class where Jane is studying. In a Mathematics Test, 
Jane made 13 mistakes, any other student in the class made fewer mistakes. Use 
the generalized pigeonhole principle to determine at least how many students 
made the same number of mistakes as each other.

ANd i answer the question this way, am i right ?

ANS:

Since any other students made fewer mistakes, hence their number of mistakes ranging from 0 to 12 (inclusively). There are 13 values (0 to 12), hence according to Pigeonhole principle, there are

```
                       29/13 + 1 = 3
```

students having the same number of mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right but I would write it as $$\lceil 29/13 \rceil=3.$$ Here $\lceil x \rceil$ is the ceiling, or *round up to the nearest integer* $\geq x$ function.

Comment: Since $29/13 > 2$, $29/13 + 1 > 3$, which is why kodlu used the ceiling function.